# ERROR: for csi_redis Cannot start service redis: Ports are not available: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:6379: bind: address already in use

Tags: laravel, docker, redis, composer-php, homebrew

I'm trying to install a project that runs:
PHP,
Laravel Framework,
Postgres DB,
NPM/NODE

I've installed postgresql and redis with brew. 
When I get to `docker-compose up -d` I'm getting this error below: (nothing else is running..I'm able to get this to work on another computer but this one doesn't want to play nice, everything similar I've looked up here hasn't worked yet.)

````
Starting csi_redis ... error

ERROR: for csi_redis  Cannot start service redis: Ports are not available: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:6379: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for redis  Cannot start service redis: Ports are not available: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:6379: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.```
````

Comment: Can you share more details? Additionally, is this related to Composer after all?

Comment: Additionally, if you already use Docker, why not run PostgreSQL and Redis in Docker containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install Redis with Homebrew, it listens on port 6379 on the host.  If your `docker-compose.yml` file has a section like

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:6379:6379'
```

that *also* tries to listen to port 6379 on the host, which produces the error you're seeing.

You probably don't need two Redises for your project, so possibly the simplest answer is to `brew uninstall redis`, or at least `brew services stop redis`.  You can interact with the containerized Redis the same way as you would have the Brew Redis.

If you need the host Redis for local development but the Docker Redis to run your project, you can pick a different port (or, potentially, delete the `ports:` entirely)

```yaml
ports:
  - '6380:6379' # keep the second port number the same
```